# Обращение к переменной из другой функции

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, variable

Всем привет, начинаю изучать Python и у меня вопрос: Можно ли обратиться к переменной, которая объявлена в другой функции? То есть чтобы работал вот такой код:

```
def func1():
    my_var = 'привет'

def func2():
    my_var1 = my_var
```

Вариант создать переменную вне функций мне не подходит. Допустим я создаю кнопку в func1, а текст кнопки хочу поменять в func2. Как такое сделать?

Comment: А чем не подходит вариант создания глобальной переменной? Ну, если так не хочется, можно передавать в функцию аргумент с новым значением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать глобальное объявление переменной, чтобы получать значение из других функций

```
def fun1():
    global myVar
    myVar = 'check value'


def fun2():
    myVarNew = myVar
    print(myVarNew)
fun1()
fun2()
```

Также можно возвращать значение функции (более правильный подход).

```
def fun1():
    myVar = 'check values'
    return myVar


def fun2():
    myVarNew = fun1()
    print(myVarNew)


fun2()
```